# Finding # of occurrences of fractions in Java

Tags: java, fractions, find-occurrences

I am trying to find and print the number of occurrences of fractions from a file in my program. Fractions that simplify down to the same number counts as an occurrence, so 12/6 counts for 6/3 as well. So far, I have separated the fractions into numerator and denominator in separate arrays. The fractions I have in the numerator and denominator came from a separate array that I received from a file. I am having trouble trying to figure out how to simplify the fractions and also find the total occurrence of them. This is what I have so far:

```
String[] split = new String[2]; //String that holds numerator and denominator
    int[] numerator = new int[100];
    int[] denominator = new int[100];

    for(int i = 0; i < numOfFractions; ++i) { //Loop through # of Lines
        split = fractions[i].split("/");  //Split the fractions at the /
        System.out.println("Test here " + fractions[i]);  //TODO --> test
        numerator[i] = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);  //Numerator
        System.out.println("Numerator = " + numerator[i]);  //TODO --> test
        denominator[i] = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);  //Denominator
        System.out.println("Denominator = " + denominator[i] + "\n");    //TODO --> test
    }

}
```

These are the fractions obtained from a file. Each fraction is on its own line, and can assume every fraction will be (A/B) format

```
6/3
4/2
5/9
80/90
800/900
5/5
1/2
1/3
1/1
1/4
2/7
2/8
2/9
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean *12/6 counts for 6/3 as well*? Does that relationship also exist between 12/6 and 8/4 and 4/2 and 2/1?

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce them by finding the greatest common divisor of the numerator and the denominator.  You can do it like so.

```
public static int gcd(int r, int s) {
    while (s > 0) {
        int t = r % s;
        r = s;
        s = t;
    }
    return r;
}
```

for `27/12`

```
int d = gcd(27,12); // returns 3

27/3 = 9
12/3 = 4
```

so the reduced fraction is `9/4`.  So every equal fraction will reduce to the same value when the numerator and denominator are divided by the GCD of those numbers.

It uses [Euclid's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)

Here is how it might be applied in your case.

- create a map to hold the reduced fraction as key and an Integer for the count.
- then convert the fraction to a numeric value and divide by the GCD
- then store the reduced fraction as a string key and increment the count for that key.

```
    
String[] s = {"10/2", "27/3", "19/4",  "15/3", "12/4",  "3/5", "9/15"};
    
Map<String, Integer> fractions = new HashMap<>();
        
        String[] s = { "10/2", "27/3", "19/4", "15/3", "12/4", "3/5",
                "9/15" };
        
        for (String vv : s) {
            String[] nd = vv.split("/");
            int n = Integer.parseInt(nd[0]);
            int d = Integer.parseInt(nd[1]);
            int div = gcd(n, d);
            n /= div;
            d /= div;
            String reduced = String.format("%d/%d", n, d);
            fractions.compute(reduced, (k,v)->v == null ? 1 : v + 1);
                
        }
        fractions.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

prints

```
3/1=1
5/1=2
3/5=2
19/4=1
9/1=1
```

Note. What
`fractions.compute(reduced, (k,v)->v == null ? 1 : v + 1);`
does is to check if the value is null.  If so, set the count to 1, otherwise add 1 to the existing count.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Fraction class as below. I would override equals() and hashCode() methods, so I can use this class with Map.

```
public class Fraction {
    int nominator;
    int denominator;

    public Fraction(int nominator, int denominator) {
        this.nominator = nominator;
        this.denominator = denominator;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return nominator + "/" + denominator;
    }  
    
    
    /**
     * The method checks if two fractions are equal. 
     * Example 1: Fraction 1 is 5/3 and Fraction 2 is 7/4.
     * The method checks if 5X4 == 7X3 and returns false.
     * Example 2: Fraction 1 is 12/6 and Fraction 2 is 8/4.
     * The method checks 12X4 == 8X6 and returns true.
     * @param obj
     * @return 
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if(obj.getClass() != this.getClass()){
            return false;
        }
        Fraction f = (Fraction)obj;
        int nominator1 = this.getNominator();
        int nominator2 = f.getNominator();
        int denominator1 = this.getDenominator();
        int denominator2 = f.getDenominator();
        nominator1 = nominator1 * denominator2;
        nominator2 = nominator2 * denominator1;
        return nominator1 == nominator2;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        if(nominator > denominator){
            hash *= getIntegerPartOfFraction(nominator, denominator);
        } else if (denominator > nominator){
            hash *= getIntegerPartOfFraction(denominator, nominator);
        }
        //System.out.println(toString() + ",hash:" + hash);
        return hash;
    }
    
    private int getIntegerPartOfFraction(int big, int small){
        int value = 0;
        while(small < big){
            big -= small;
            value++;
        }
        return value;
    }

    public int getNominator() {
        return nominator;
    }

    public int getDenominator() {
        return denominator;
    }
}
```

Then, I would create Fraction objects from your data input file. I understand you already have retrieved integer values of nominators and denominators. The following code creates a new List with Fraction objects.

```
   List<Fraction> fractions = new ArrayList(){{
       add(new Fraction(1, 2));
       add(new Fraction(2, 4));
       add(new Fraction(4, 8));
       add(new Fraction(8, 16));
       add(new Fraction(5, 2));
       add(new Fraction(10, 4));
       add(new Fraction(20, 8));
       add(new Fraction(1, 2));
       add(new Fraction(3, 8));
       add(new Fraction(9, 24));      
   }};
```

Once you populate the list with your input data, you can use a Map to find and print the result.

```
       Map<Fraction,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
       for(Fraction f: fractions){
           if(map.containsKey(f)){
               int value = map.get(f);
               value++;
               map.put(f, value);
           } else {
               map.put(f, 1);
           }
       }
       
       System.out.println(map);
```

Here is the output for the given fractions.

```
{1/2=5, 5/2=3, 3/8=2}
```

Comment: The hashCode implementation is buggy, since it will return different values for equivalent fractions

Comment: And in your equals method,  `denominator2` should be assigned `f.getDenominator()`  But that is irrelevant until you fix your hashCode.

Comment: Thank you Rocco, WJS for pointing out the bug and typo. I have updated the code.